# Converting a collection of int to hex and sending by serial

Tags: python, encoding, type-conversion, serial-port, byte

I need to send "frame" by serial port, so i built a some class frame with method 'as_tuple' which collects data frame this object, calculates control sum and returns a tuple of int's (e.g. (85, 1, 71, 0, 157) (hex '55 01 47 00 9D').
Which is the best way to convert it to hex and then to bytes which allows me to send it by serial?

I do it by

```py
' '.join(f'{i:02x}' 
    for i in (85, 1, 71, 0, 157)).encode()
>> b'55 01 47 00 9d'
```

But I feel that's not the best way.

Comment: instead of hardcoding the values to encode like you have, you should have them in a variable and do the same but using a variable.

Comment: This is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The `.encode()` at the end is the only way to convert a string to bytes, if that's what your interface requires.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) class and its [hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method for this:

```
>>> data = bytes((85, 1, 71, 0, 157))
>>> data
b'U\x01G\x00\x9d'
>>> type(data)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> data.hex()
'550147009d'
>>> data.hex(":")
'55:01:47:00:9d'
```